# User created classes

Tags: python, class

I am learning Python, following a book (Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner, 3rd Edition).
The book gives an example of a basic Sims like application, where a finite number of "critters" are created, and the user must feed and play with them, increasing their boredom and hunger values.
I was practicing using classes, and tried to make my own game. The user was presented with a menu where the user could; buy/create a new sim, delete an old one, or interact with existing ones.
The problem I'm having is with creating new classes. The user is initially presented with a screen asking what they would like to do, and if they press X, they are taken to the createnewsim function. However the problem is when a new class is made:

```
nameofsim = input("what would you like to call your new sim?")
newsim = sim(nameofsim)
```

If the user were to make another, it would overwrite the existing one, since the name newsim cannot be changed, as I discovered in a previous question, more or less.

So, how do I allocate new object names, or prevent old sims from being overwritten, allowing for the creations of more than one new sim??

Comment: Fyi, you want to use `raw_input` instead of `input` since the latter evaluates the string as a python expression.

Comment: that depends on if they are using python 2.x or 3.x

Comment: As a note, it's a Python convention (see PEP 8 - http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to use ``CamelCase`` for class names.

Comment: Your question is clear, but FYI you are creating new *instances* of the sim class (new objects), not new classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either store your sim classes in a list or a dictionary; e.g.

```
class Sim(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

names = ['tim','dave','jane']
sims = {}
for name in names:
    sims[name] = Sim(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jakob Bowyer already answered your question, but I thought I'd add a note about Python variables. Consider the following code:

```
newSim = Sim('Bob')

oldSim = newSim

newSim = Sim('George')
```

In this example, the end result would be `oldSim = Bob` and `newSim = George`.  Notice how the object that the variable refers to is not destroyed or overwritten with variable assignment. The only thing that changes is the location in memory that the variable name is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary of sims like this

```
sim_dict = {}
while True:
    nameofsim = input("what would you like to call your new sim?")
    if nameofsim == "":
        break
    sim_dict[nameofsim] = Sim(nameofsim)
```

If the user creates a sim called 'dave' you could access it by using

```
sim_dict['dave']
```

But when you are writing the program you can't guess what names the user will give to the sims, so often you will be accessing them in a loop like this

```
for nameofsim, sim in sim_dict.items():
    if sim.birthday==today:
        sim.age+= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough code, to help you sufficiently. So we can't tell if it's possible to save the state of a Sim and continue with a freshly created. It's also unclear what a sim is! Is it the whole game or just a "critter" as you called it?

But in general you could do a mapping in a dictionary like:

```
sims = {}
nameofsim = input("what would you like to call your new sim?")
if nameofsim in sims:
    newsim = sims[nameofsim]
else:
    newsim = sim(nameofsim)
    sims[nameofsim] = newsim
```

It also seems you didn't grasp some concepts here:

1. classes in general are distinct different to objects (in python classes are special types of objects). Objects are to classes in a type-of relationship. This distinction is important because of inheritance and polymorphism in object-oriented paradigms! champ and boy are both dogs, but champ is a labrador and 2 years old and boy is a dobbermann and 5 years old. so both are of the *type* dog - which makes boy and champs to objects of the class dog!

    As you see, the abstract class *dog* isn't living - it's just an abstract concept of a being. But 
   the objects *champ* and *boy* are the living instances of the class *dog*!
2. with the statement `newsim = sim(nameofsim)` your are doing the following:

   1. creating an object of the type `sim`
   2. initializining it with the argument provided by `nameofsim`
   3. assigning this object to an arbitray name -> variable `newsim`

but the variable `newsim` is **NOT** the object! the object may exist even without a variable-name of it's own. The use of a variable just provides you a convenient access to the object.